# I think hibernate is very stupid in loading it's config file

Tags: hibernate

I want to all my xml config in WEB-INF/conf folder including the hibernate.cfg.xml and `xxxx.hbm.xml`.

I try

```
cfg.configure(req.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
```

then "`file not find`"

then

I try

```
cfg.configure(new File(req.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml")));
```

the config file is loaded, but the `xxx.hbm.xml` files just cannot find.

Does anyone can tell mu how to load the `cfg.xml` and all of its `xxx.hbm.xml`?

Comment: I don't want put it in classpath

Answer (score 0):

> I try
>   cfg.configure(req.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
>   then "file not find"

From the docs

> Use the mappings and properties specified in the given application resource. The format of the resource is defined in hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd.
>   The resource is found via getConfigurationInputStream(resource).

So if you are specifying a file, you need to provide a file object to the constructor ( using `new File()` ... )

> the config file is loaded, but the xxx.hbm.xml files just cannot find.
>   Does anyone can tell mu how to load the cfg.xml and all of its xxx.hbm.xml

This looks like a simple issue of specifying relative paths or absolute paths inside the cfg.xml. Although I always advise using annotated classes over xml , still I would advise you to verify that the paths you are specifying are indeed correct and the respective resource does infact exist